# Scan dir and make array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I wanted to scan directory `https://equestria.space/videosmlp/fim/` through php (To scan .mp4 files because there are only them). And then after scan and print i have this in index.php

```
  <?php
  $dir = "../videosmlp/fim";
  $scans = scandir($dir);
  $episodes = array();

  foreach($scans as $k=>$v){
      array_push($episodes,['id'=>$k,'filename'=>$v]);
  }
  ?>

  <?php foreach ($episodes as $episode){?>
  <video id="<?php echo $episode['filename']; ?>" width="960" height="540" data-overscale="false">
      <source type="video/mp4" src="<?php echo $episode['filename']; ?>.mp4" />
  </video>
  <?php } ?>
```

I have video in https://equestria.space/moviesmlp/fim
I want to output video in https://equestria.space/series

Getting error

```
Warning: scandir(../videosmlp/fim,../videosmlp/fim): The system cannot find the path specified. (code: 3) in S:\equestriaspace\series\index.php on line 1011

Warning: scandir(../videosmlp/fim): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in S:\equestriaspace\series\index.php on line 1011

Warning: scandir(): (errno 2): No such file or directory in S:\equestriaspace\series\index.php on line 1011

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in S:\equestriaspace\series\index.php on line 1014
```

Comment: You are using an URL in `scandir()`, not a directory, see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

Comment: provide absolute path or relative path to directory

Comment: as you said that you mp4 files are in separate disk (as you do that with Apache). So none of the code will work. Please share  folder structure completely. Not half part of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your `desired` array with a simple `foreach()` like the following-

```
$dir = "/path/to/directory";
$scans = scandir($dir);
$episodes = array();

foreach($scans as $k=>$v){
    if (preg_match('/.mp4$/', $v))
        array_push($episodes,['id'=>$k,'filename'=>$v]);
}
```

at the end `$episodes` will contain the array. `$dir` need to be `absolute` or `relative` path to your directory.

Then loop through the episodes array to get individual episode.

```
<?php foreach ($episodes as $episode){?>
    <?php echo $episode['filename']; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: How do i print then for HTML this? `<?php echo $episodes['filename']; ?>` like this?

Comment: @Jengas I have updated my answer, try to update it with your own view code/logic

Comment: Nope. Give this error
`Warning: scandir(../videosmlp/fim,../videosmlp/fim): The system cannot find the path specified. (code: 3) in S:\equestriaspace\series\index.php on line 1011


Warning: scandir(../videosmlp/fim): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in S:\equestriaspace\series\index.php on line 1011

Warning: scandir(): (errno 2): No such file or directory in S:\equestriaspace\series\index.php on line 1011


Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in S:\equestriaspace\series\index.php on line 1014

`

Comment: update your question with directory structure, where your index.php is and where is your desired directory.

Comment: and how do you scan only mp4 files?

Answer (score 0):

Search about [ftp](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php) to have a result what you want ! `scandir` need a `path` not an `url`

Once, you can abtain what you want like this :

```
<?php
$path_of_films = 'path/to/filmdirecoty';
$list_episodes = scandir($path_of_films);
$i = 1;

foreach($list_episodes as $name)
{
   if($name != '.' OR $name != '..')
   {
     $episodes[] = [
         'id' => $i,
         'filename'=> $name
       ]
     $i++;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A URL is not a directory, and you cannot simply scan it for the files it contains. All HTTP allows you to do is ask the server to give you some content based on a particular string.

The simplest way for a server to respond to the strings you give it is to map them to directories and files on disk, but it might instead look in some database, or generate content based on some arcane mathematical formula. It can do this for a URL ending in a / just as easily as one ending in something that looks like a filename.

So the only way to know what "files" (URLs with filename-like bits on the end) are "in" (can be formed to look like) a "directory" (a URL which ends in /) is if the server has arranged some way to tell you, like an index page.